# C# / .Net 8 / Blazor server disconnects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Is there any new direction on how to handle the following blazor server signalR disconnections in .NET 8 core?

From what I've read, there are not really any new fixes for this in a standpoint of blazor server.

I know they've added the InteractiveAuto etc.

Error:
Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality.

[image: A]

[image: Other image]

[image: Other image 3]

I've tried everything on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779601/auto-reconnect-blazor-serverside/75374020#75374020)

Comment: It seems that you have just started this project, could  you share your repo? And please hide your sensitive info,  so that we could investigate the issue.

Comment: @JasonPan: What do you mean repo? This is on my azure website. I actually just got another error as well.

Comment: I mean if you could create a brand new project which could reproduce the issue, it will easy for us to investigate the issue.

Comment: It seems the code issue, it's hard for us to provide a solution for you without any code.

Comment: @JasonPan: Okay, I have recently setup the project. I'll have to recreate it from scratch maybe tomorrow, if I can. The application now has sync fusion added. I've placed it on Azure app service and I really only see it when I'm on my mobile phone.

Comment: @JasonPan: How do I upload the actual project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256169/discussion-between-tvb2754-and-jason-pan).

Comment: I think it is related to an old not not yet solved Microsoft Blazor problem with SignalR... as described here, I am facing exactly the same problem:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638451/reconnecting-issue-in-blazor-server/74642664#74642664 - with some suggestions on how to solve the problem. 
As you can see here, the issue is not solved on Microsoft's side yet: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32113

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder: Yep, I agree. It is frustrating. I've got around it to a degree, but still isn't the answer.

Comment: This had helped me for better understanding: 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779601/auto-reconnect-blazor-serverside
2) https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0
3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989226/signalr-client-does-not-call-the-reconnecting-event-when-the-server-shuts-down 
4) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V5DMInE4UU
5) https://www.peug.net/en/blazor-manage-disconnects/